# Xamarin. Upgrade Azure Mobile Service to App Service - TableController

Tags: .net, azure, xamarin

Recentaly I uptaded my Azure back-end project from App Services to Mobile Services.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-net-upgrading-from-mobile-services

In my project I use Table Controllers

```
[MobileAppController]
public class ChildController : TableController<Child>
{
    public Child GetChildByEmail(string email)
    {
        return _context.Children.SingleOrDefault(ch => ch.Email == email);
    }
}
```

Now, before the upgrade the url to the GetChildByEmail method was:

```
/api/child/email
```

so, I was calling the method as follow:

```
Child result = await _service.MobileServiceClient.InvokeApiAsync<Child>
("child", HttpMethod.Get, new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "email", 
email } });
```

It was workin fine. But after the upgrade the url to the method is

```
/tables/child/email
```

so InvokeApiAsync is not working because it is calling

```
/api/child/email
```

I tried to decorate the method with the "Route" attribute

```
Route["api/child"]
```

but it did not work. Is there any way to keep that method in the TableController and force InvokeApiAsync to call /tables/child/email instead /api/child/email? Or the only way to solve that issue is to move the method to the ApiContoller (which works fine)?

Answer (score 0):

I sovled the problem:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("ActionApi", "api/{controller}");
```